# Numbers and Dashes

Tags: mathematics, cipher

Here's a fun puzzle I created!

Decode this statement:

```
45372-32140-59386-41506_45282-42025-689_82511-99281-64294_32180-26467-41326-54003
18690-79751-59300-2316_83139-5649-77571_6568-32761-90755-92403_84597-53555-16773-66327_12269-93515-12971-38009_80378-81106_73344-72795_60133-45974-3517
77133-88846-33287-65270_1421-60736_65980-45909-48005-48170_34508-51220-23061-91147_56759_81777-34417-8668
```

Hints:

Hint 1:

> Pay attention to the sum of the digits of the numbers, rather than the numbers themselves.

---

[Next Part](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116469)

Comment: I assume the fact that there are mostly '-' signs but sometimes '_' between the number blocks and the fact that there are mostly 5 digits but some are 4 digits are both deliberate and meant to be that way?

Comment: Yes, those are all meant to be. The '-' dashes and '_' dashes both mean different things. Remember to pay attention to the sum of the digits of the numbers, rather than the numbers themselves, as stated in hint 1.

Comment: rot13(Vf "Jvyy erirny vs hafbyirq ol Wha 6 ng 6:00cz CFG." n uvag be qb lbh npghnyyl zrna vg.)

Comment: @VarunW. I meant that the hint will be revealed at that time; there is no underlying coded message. The decoding does not include rot13, in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First:

> we find the sum of the digits of each number. To avoid confusion in the next step, I've replaced the dashes with spaces, and replaced the underscores with forward slashes:
>
> 21 10 31 16 / 21 13 23 / 17 29 25 / 14 25 16 12
>  24 29 17 12 / 24 24 27 / 25 19 26 18 / 33 23 24 24 / 20 23 20 20 / 26 16 / 21 30 / 13 29 16
>  21 34 23 20 / 8 22 / 28 27 17 20 / 20 10 12 22 / 32 / 30 19 28

Next:

> We replace odd numbers with a dash, and even numbers with a dot:
>
> -.-./---/---/.-../.--./..-/--../--../.-../../-./--./-.-./../.--./...././.-.

Finally:

> We decode this from Morse code to get the message:
>
> **COOL PUZZLING CIPHER**