# Numbers and Dashes again... but with letters this time!

Tags: mathematics, cipher

[Previous Part](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116463)

Here's a fun puzzle I created!

Decode this statement:

```
1189-163-j-1032
7558-7481-b-2775-f-5212-f-1417-3503-512
3086-f-f-5342-1188
f-8499-8131-9715-f-6382-f-3547-4730
1601-v-7513-9463-5419-j-6253-6792
v-2015-3565-f-693-5655-f-b-643-215
9535-9055-f
2004-j-5189-7703-f-355
```

Hint 1 (for the numbers):

> For each number `N`, consider `N (mod 26)` and how that relates to the alphabet.

Hint 2 (for the letters):

> For each letter, consider something that they all have in common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the numbers:

> Take the value mod 26 and map it to the alphabet (0 = a, 1 = b, ..., 25 = z).

For the letters:

> Replace it with the letter that comes before it in the alphabet (b = a, f = e, j = i, p = o, v = u).

The solution:

> **"this statements seems extremely puzzling underneath the cipher"**