# Letters and dashes... but without the numbers this time!

Tags: mathematics, cipher

[Previous Part](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116469)

Here's **another** fun puzzle!

Decode this statement:

```
lzxftzwclctgwkpc-gnggh-fvnbazlslocpul-vthprcipykxex-euzbpttnzywv
tlw-wulttuqt-jxzkweczmruyo-zyhclelxjtszs-xnzfzslimysoyjybpiiwirswb-hyjycxifkvowyaratsbwmi-x-knszxxughsorbzdxvvuu
tovbfxfhdqnrurar-pmpnsynryhcsssxgkezuca-bxs-fdehevnnqruaamkyortms-uexzhillsonkqohcff-kxbew
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is a quite easy cipher. Finding the length of all words in `lzxftzwclctgwkpc-gnggh-fvnbazlslocpul-vthprcipykxex-euzbpttnzywv tlw-wulttuqt-jxzkweczmruyo-zyhclelxjtszs-xnzfzslimysoyjybpiiwirswb-hyjycxifkvowyaratsbwmi-x-knszxxughsorbzdxvvuu tovbfxfhdqnrurar-pmpnsynryhcsssxgkezuca-bxs-fdehevnnqruaamkyortms-uexzhillsonkqohcff-kxbew` we get numerals within 1~26, applying A1Z26 and then rot13 gives `crazy puzzling cipher`.

Comment: You solved it in a slightly different way than I planned, but yours works as well.

Comment: Are you willing to share your solution, post a hint, or change the question such that my approach will not work (or is this impossible?) @smlee Thank you

Comment: Sorry, here is my solution: rot13(Gnxr gur yratguf bs gur "jbeqf" naq pbaireg gubfr ahzoref gb yrggref. Pbaireg gur yrggref gb ahzoref naq fhogenpg 5 (ybbc bire 26). Pbaireg onpx gb yrggref. Nccyl ebg13. Pbaireg gur yrggref gb ahzoref naq nqq 5 (ybbc bire 26).) (hopefully hint 2 makes more sense now!)

Comment: NOTE: I haven't actually heard of A1Z26 before... I will research it. Do you think maybe I should remove hint 2 for clarity??

Comment: @smlee Won't it still work if you only do the rot13? A1Z26 is simply "change numbers into letters", 1->A and Z->26

Comment: OMG I just realized your right! Sorry for making such a simple cipher... I'm new. Hope you enjoyed it though! I'll make my next one more complicated. Thanks for solving it anyway! (I removed hint 2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136856/discussion-between-nobody-needs-names-and-smlee).